# Connecting local MySQL database linked to Java project into another computer

Tags: java, mysql, database, netbeans

I have a Java project with a local MySQL database linked to it. It has a login page with stored login details in the database. Let's say this is stored in Computer A. I have made this project into an executable jar file. How can I open the jar file in computer B  if the database was created locally in Computer A?

Is it possible to link the database from Computer A to Computer B?

Thank you!

Comment: Does ComputerA/MySQL allow remote connections?

Comment: Are both machines on the same LAN or are they completely independent? If the latter, then A will have to be set up such that its MySql service can be routed to through a public facing address. If the former, then the situation is simpler

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can access it using your localhost ip. you will have to connect the wifi hotspot of second device from the first device.
once connected you will have to fight the ip address. if you are on windows you can use ipconfig. Then instead of localhost you will have to use the ip address as well as the port.
I had done this with apache and MySQL. if you are using only MySQL then some changes may have to be made.